How to apply networkX graphs and A* search to large numpy array
I have a photo (coverted into an array) which contains x,y and a f(x,y) parameter for each x and y. Effectivley I want to simulate random points in the photo and then use a minimum cost algrithm to move between the points by minimising the penalties given by the f(x,y). I have looked into creating a network (graph using NetworkX) but keep getting memory errors because the graph ends up being so big. I'm open to other ideas other than NetworkX if you think theres better ways to solve my problem.
I'll be honest its my first time using NetworkX and I am a bit lost as to how to apply it. This code isnt perfect but is more to illustrate what I have tried to do so any pointers would be apprecaited.
If you think that complete changes are needed/different ideas then that would be great.
Create an empty graph
G = nx.Graph()


for y in range(image_shape[0]):
    for x in range(image_shape[1]):
        G.add_node((x, y))

for u in G.nodes():
    for v in G.nodes():
        if u != v:
            weight_uv = distances_exp[int(u[1]), int(u[0])] + distances_exp[int(v[1]), int(v[0])]
            G.add_edge(u, v, weight=weight_uv)


min_cost_paths = []
for i in range(len(final_points)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(final_points)):
        source = tuple(final_points[i])
        target = tuple(final_points[j])
        min_cost_path = nx.astar_path(G, source, target, weight='weight')
        min_cost_paths.append(min_cost_path)


for path in min_cost_paths:
    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        cv2.line(heatmap, path[i], path[i + 1], (0, 255, 0), 10)  # Draw a green line for each path segment`

This is a quick idea of what I have tried but it doesnt work. The distances holds the f(x,y) values I mentioned and the final_points are the random points I am looking to join together.
